# Objective-C - Initialize object with default values based on dictionary

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I have a dictionary of predefined values:

```
 UID | minVal | maxVal
-----------------------
 DAB |  1000  |  2000
 ECB |  -500  |  3000
```

and a class

```
interface MCProperty : NSObject
@property(...) NSString *uid;
@property(...) NSNumber *minVal;
@property(...) NSNumber *maxVal;
@end
```

Now, when I'm creating MCProperty object i.e.:

```
MCProperty property = [[MCProperty alloc] initWithString:@"DAB"];
```

I wish to setup **minVal** to **1000** and **maxVal** to **2000** based on dictionary. How can I accomplished that?

PS. How should I store "dictionary" (defined constants in class, NSArray etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, look at using `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:` as this is the minimum amount of code. It requires that the dictionary keys match the property names.

If you can't then you need some mapping logic between the dictionary keys and properties. Add this into a method on your class, called `configureWithDictionary` (or similar) and define your constants in the most restrictive place possible.